# Can someone please explain me the answer of this: React embed components into one

Tags: reactjs

*Can someone please explain to me the answer to this: like how are we embedding and whats ReactDOM.render() doing?*

Question: How can you embed two or more components into one?

Answer: We can embed components into one in the following way:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(          
             
<div>
               
<h1>Hello</h1>
 
                <Header/>
            </div>
 
        );
    }
}
class Header extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return
 
<h1>Header Component</h1>
   
   };
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <MyComponent/>, document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have a div or any other component that surrounds your other components then you can make use of the short [syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax) and that goes as follow:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(          
             
            <>
                <h1>Header Component</h1>
                <div>
                <h1>Hello</h1>
                </div
            </>
 
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyComponent/>, document.getElementById('content')
);
```